# Custom HTTP field in request and response

Tags: java, http

I want to identify which response corresponds to which request in Java.
It is easy if each request has its own connection, but if many requests are sent and received through the same socket, it will become hard.

After searching the web, it seems that the solution is to add a custom HTTP header.
Since I do not have access to the server, my question is: Can I add a field to http request and have the server return the same field to me?

EDIT: To be more clear, I am writing a proxy server. So I will receive a http request and relay it to the server and do the same for the response. My question if focused on the requests that are sent through a specific socket.

Comment: you want to intercept it at which layer, server side ?

Comment: What I am doing is writing a custom http proxy server and I want to compute the response time of each request. Therefore, I need to know the correspondence of requests and responses.

Comment: can you controll webserver as well ?

Comment: In the test scenarios yes. But ultimately, all I can do is sit in between and receive request, modify them if necessary, and forward them, receive the response, and forward it, and do some calculation ...

Comment: @JigarJoshi did you mean the webserver I am running (proxy) on or the webserver of the actual server? I can control the first one. The second one only in test scenarios